# My Scala program won't print anything

Tags: scala

Basically I'm trying to write a program that has a list of books and authors and then prints 2 things out, `res1`, which should print the book titles of the authors that have the name "Andrei" in it and `res2` that should print the book titles that have the string "programare".

```
case class Book(title: String, authors: List[String]){

  val books: List[Book] = List( 
  Book("Interpretarea programelor pe calculator", 
  List("Grigore, Alexe", "Antonio, Vucu G.")), 
  Book("Calcul diferential si integral", 
  List("Andrei, Ioan", "Anghel, Radulescu")), 
  Book("Introducere in limbajul de programare C++", 
  List("Andrei, Nicolae")),
  Book("Introducere in programarea functionala", 
  List("Dinu, Constantin")), 
  Book("Programare in limbajul Java", 
  List("Daniel, Iosif", "Gicu, Alin", "Victor, Niculescu ", "Viorel,        Andurache")))

  val res1 = for (b <- carti; a <- b.authors if a startsWith "Andrei") yield    b.title

  val res2 = for (b <- carti if (b.title indexOf "programare") >= 0) yield b.title

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

   println(res1);
   println(res2);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, lots of problems.

All that stuff you are doing? It's getting done in the constructor of Book, and redone for every instance.

Your main method? That's gets compiled to instance method of Book, not a static method, so it does not serve an an entry point for an executable program. You can extend `App` as Dmitry suggests, or explicitly define your main method in a companion object rather than a class. Companion object methods get static "forwarders", so you do end up with the desired main method.

Oh, and scala won't compile from English to Romanian, so if you name the variable `books` the for comprehensions can't work with it as `carti`!

```
object Book {
  def main( argv : Array[String] ) : Unit = {
    val books: List[Book] = List( 
      Book("Interpretarea programelor pe calculator", List("Grigore, Alexe", "Antonio, Vucu G.")), 
      Book("Calcul diferential si integral", List("Andrei, Ioan", "Anghel, Radulescu")), 
      Book("Introducere in limbajul de programare C++", List("Andrei, Nicolae")),
      Book("Introducere in programarea functionala", List("Dinu, Constantin")), 
      Book("Programare in limbajul Java", List("Daniel, Iosif", "Gicu, Alin", "Victor, Niculescu ", "Viorel, Andurache"))
    )

    val res1 = for (b <- books; a <- b.authors if a startsWith "Andrei") yield    b.title
    val res2 = for (b <- books if (b.title indexOf "programare") >= 0) yield b.title

    println(res1);
    println(res2);
  }
}
case class Book(title: String, authors: List[String])
```

Comment: Yes, i know the programming language won't do any translating, that was my bad, as i had my code in romanian and i quickly translated everything except for that part. And i tried adding an object called Book myself, but then i nested the class in it and it didn't work. Now i can see how the layout of the program should have been and it works, thanks a lot.

Comment: oh, i got that, i was just teasing you, enjoyed seeing the romanian in your code!

Answer (score 1):

Use scala.App trait as a main class, like

```
object Test extends App {
    println("anything")
}
```